# How to enter a name of file in textfield and display the file in textarea?

Tags: java

I need to enter the name of a file in textfield and display that document in a textarea.

My code works only if I enter full path of a file to a textfield, but my task is to enter only the file name not full path. How can I do it?

`input` is a textfield and `output` is a textarea

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    try{
         FileReader fr=new FileReader(input.getText());
         BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(fr);
         output.read(reader," ");
         output.setLineWrap(true);
         output.setWrapStyleWord(true);

       }catch(IOException ioe){

        System.err.println(ioe);
        System.exit(1);
       }

}
```

Comment: If you can't do the below answer.. I think you should take a look at this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a complete path for getting a file in Java. If you have an absolute path, you can just add this path as `String`.

```
String path = "/path/to/my/files/";
FileReader fr=new FileReader(path + input.getText());
```